# Javascript autocomplete cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am cloning a row table with a autocomplete on one of its cells.
The problem is the autocomplete only works on my default(1st row) row, the cloned autocomplete fields don't work anymore.

Here's the jQuery code for the autocomplete

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
    $(".tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

My javascript code for cloning

```
function insRow()
{
        var x=document.getElementById('appendTable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;
        new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
        var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];  //month
        inp1.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
        inp1.id += len;
        var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[1];  //day
        inp2.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[1].value;
        inp2.id += len;
        var inp3 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[2];  //year
        inp3.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[2].value;
        inp3.id += len;
        x.appendChild( new_row );
        a++; //checker
}
```

The html part where the cloning goes

```
<td>
    <div class="ui-widget">
    <input class="tags">
</td>
```

I already used class instead of ID for the autocomplete but it doesn't work. What could I add on my cloning code for the autocomplete to work?

Comment: would be easier to solve if you include a jsfiddle

Comment: Its a fluke, but you can try `var new_row = $('#appendTable tr:eq(0)').clone(true).get(0);` use jQuery to clone

Answer (score 0):

Try as below, it should work

```
function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('appendTable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];  //month
    inp1.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
    inp1.id += len;
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[1];  //day
    inp2.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[1].value;
    inp2.id += len;
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[2];  //year
    inp3.value=x.rows[a].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[2].value;
    inp3.id += len;
    x.appendChild( new_row );
    a++; //checker
    $(".tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

}
```

Refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Za3Vu/38/) this should also give you an idea to solve it.